# react-native build a standalone app in dev mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Problem**

My RN application is crashing as soon as it starts (in release mode) and I can't figure out why. I'd like to build a debug version of the app that shows the error that is being encountered.

**What I tried**

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev true --entry-file index.android.js \
--bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
--assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/


./gradlew assembleDebug
```

When I do this though, the debug build is still reading from the development server.

Comment: Usually this is the proguard configuration striping too many classes. Reproduce the error but check the log from the device and post it.

Comment: Thanks @sfratini - I'll give this a try tomorrow when I'm back at work!