# React Native application crashing immediately - no linked packages

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to debug an old project for quite some time. This project was crashing every time I installed and ran a release build with `./gradlew assembleRelease` and `react-native run-android --variant=release`. The weird thing is, the debug version was running just fine (`react-native run-android`).

Finally, I gave up and moved all of the javascript to completely brand-new project, attaching it only via the `index.js` that came when I ran `react-native init <project>`.

Again, the project runs just fine in debug but the release build crashes immediately without any indication of what could be going wrong.

**Details**

I'm using *react-native: 0.50.3*, *react: 16.1.1*, and I've stripped the project down so that there are no linked packages (as far as I'm aware, my project is now completely written in javascript).

**Question**

I'd like to at least figure out how I might begin debugging this. I posted a question [react-native build a standalone app in dev mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333854/react-native-build-a-standalone-app-in-dev-mode) earlier because I'd like for the app to give me details instead of crashing. How can I figure out the root cause of the crash?

Comment: Were you ever successful in creating a release build? Maybe try generating a new keystore to sign your app and going through the whole signing process again. Instructions [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

Comment: @alexdriedger - turns out there was an issue with a library that I was using. What helped me to debug was to run Android Studio along side the release app and read the monitor output - I actually didn't realize you could do that with a release build.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this isn't necessarily a solution, but it turns out there was a version mismatch that wasn't showing itself in the debug build. I'm still not sure the exact issue is.

My advice would be to run the release build with Android Studio running. I didn't know this was possible, and as soon as I learned, the problem was fixed after I was able to identify the problematic package and updating it.